# Android: having an activity call another separate java file, which represents the on top animation

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I am making a little game, which at the moment, works kinda passively (it only runs and does actions when the user hits buttons).

But i want to add animations on top of it, so i have this kind of a layers, where the bottom layers is a normal view with buttons and texts, and on top of it i have kind of a surfaceview running canvas animation with threads.

i am also looking to make these 2 separate java files, since i know that each activity represents one view at a time, could i some how make my bottom view, to call add on top of him the surfaceview and let him update him self as he should, while the bottom view remains passive?

Answer (score 0):

Its right that one Activity represents one View which doesn't mean that you can't stack them. 
You can use a LinearLayout with a `weight_sum` of 1, add your SurfaceView with a weight of 0.8 and your BottomView a weight of 0.2. 
This will allow you, to handle them separately

Comment: what does weight exactly mean? it's like saying that my surfaceview will 80% out of the screen( his parent) and bottom view 20%?

Comment: exactly. You can give Views prozentual-like sizes

Answer (score 0):

An Activity is not a View, but instead houses a collection of Views. What you need is a single activity, but have the layout split into two sections. You could then, say have a LinearLayout containing a SurfaceView and another layout container below it containing your Buttons and text. You should then be able to animate your SurfaceView independently of the container below it, which seems like what you want to be able to do.

For example, something like;

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface">

    </SurfaceView>

    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/controls">
    <!-- Buttons and text -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate() method of your Activity, you would:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
// Now you should be able to animate the surfaceView independent to the rest of the elements in the activity
surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.controls);
// Rest of initialization code.
```

Comment: so what your saying, is i need to have 3 activities one for the parent LinearLayout (referring to your example at the moment), which is only goal is to create him self, , and have two seperate activities, for the surfaceView and the Bototm Linear layout which are the actually real activities and let the parent Linearlayout set the view of each of his surfaceView and LinearLayout to the 2 other activities? (I hope i was clear xD)

Comment: Hi Dan, I have updated my answer, let me know if this is your problem, if not, could you clarify your question a little further?